# PHP -Converting php object to NEO4j Cypher query format

Tags: php, neo4j, neo4jphp

I need to convert a php object into a NEO4j Cypher query key/value format.

That format for example looks like:

```
MATCH (you:Person {name:"You"}) <-- Note the {name:"You"} part
```

I tried `json_encode()` but of course it's adding to the keys double quotes.

Comment: and what's wrong with the quotes? Keys in JS objects are Strings anyways ...

Comment: Why do the double quotes matter?

Comment: I'm using neo4j DB and I'm sending the data in a query. The Cypher language doesn't accept the double quotes in the keys

Comment: @AvivPaz Are you connecting to that DB in PHP or javascript?

Comment: @MikeBrant I'm connecting in PHP.

Comment: @Aviv Paz Then why is this tagged with javascript, why are you trying to serialize to JSON?  Just searching for Cypher and I get a better picture for what you are looking for.  You should add examples to your post to make your intent more clear. I would imagine you should be working with one of the available PHP libraries to abstract that Cypher query language out for you to some extent, or simply create a simply function to convert key/value pairs into the string format you are looking for. I would think that would be trivial.

Comment: @AvivPaz That is not really "javascript" format - it's just a format. I have edited your questrion a bit to hopefully direct toward NEO4j users who can better help. Take a look at the wrapper libraries for NEO4j PHP.

Comment: How do you convert the object to the query ?

Comment: If you are sending data from a PHP application to Neo4j, you are using the REST interface. You should look into parameterized Cypher queries, where you send your Cypher with a placeholder, and also send along normally json-encoded data that will fill in the placeholder. Or, use one of the available neo4j PHP libraries, they will handle that for you.

Comment: Just use parameters as Josh said.